# React if statement in asynchronous loop question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios

Help, I cannot seem to figure out how to solve this problem:

```
array.map(object => {
   console.log(this.state.newArr) // [] didn't update despite setState
   if (this.state.newArr.length === 0) {
      axios.get('http://localhost/')
      .then(res => {
         this.setState(prevState => ({ newArr: [...prevState.newArr, res] })) // setState here
      })
   }
})
```

Edit: updated code implemented the answers, but still doesn't work atm.

Comment: We need more context. Where is this loop located?

Comment: Its in componentDidMount(), what I mean by loop is the map function.

Comment: `componentDidMount` only runs one time. It will not run again after your state is updated.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, but it should at least finish the map loop right?

Comment: It does, but `setState` is async, so it will no be using the updated value when it sets it. I'll answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

Async/await pattern can be a solution. Never tried it in a map but it would be something like this :

```
array.map(async object => {
  if (this.state.newArr.length === 0) {
     const response = await axios.get('http://localhost/');
     await this.setStateAsync({ newArr: [...this.state.newArr, response] });
     // or without the setStateAsync 
     // this.setState(prevState => ({ newArr: [...prevState.newArr, response] })); 
  }
});

const setStateAsync = state => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.setState(state, resolve)
  });
}
```

Comment: @ErisSuryaputra Does the setStateAsync works properly ? If yes then i'll remove my previous update

Comment: Nope, I thought it worked before but unfortunately it still don't

Comment: There's no advantage to using the updater if you aren't going to use the `prevState` passed in.

Comment: @BrianThompson thank you i forgot to change that as well. It's edited :)

Answer (score 0):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is [async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), meaning when setting state in a loop you will not yet have the updated state values. When you make state updates based on previous state values, you should use the updater form of `setState`.

### Example of whats going wrong

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arr: []
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    [1,2,3].forEach((i) => {
      // setState is async, 
      // so it has not updated by the next loop
      // meaning its the same every cycle
      console.log(this.state.arr)
      this.setState({ arr: [...this.state.arr, i] });
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    // Only the last enty is in the array
    console.log('final', this.state.arr)
    return (<div>test</div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

### Example of the correct way

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arr: []
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    [1,2,3].forEach((i) => {
      // Use the updater form so you are guaranteed
      // to have the most recent copy of state each update
      this.setState((prevState) => ({ arr: [...prevState.arr, i] }));
    })
  }
  
  render() {
   console.log('final: ', this.state.arr)
    return (<div>test</div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Another feature of `setState` that may come in handy here is the callback option.
You may pass a second argument to `setState` that is a function. That function will be called **after** the state is updated, so you can add logic there that is dependent on those updated values.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      arr: []
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    [1,2,3].forEach((i) => {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({ arr: [...prevState.arr, i] }), () => {
        console.log('updated: ', this.state);
      });
      console.log('not updated: ', this.state);
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (<div>test</div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: updater form is nice but I don't think it answer the question alone.The axios request isn't awaited and therefore the state update, even with the update form, won't be synchronous.

Comment: Oh you are right, after testing with the new prevState. This still hasn't solved the axios problem :( sorry